# typedef visibility

Tags: c, struct, typedef, opacity

I have a ".c .h" couple of files.
In the header file (.h), I define 2 **typedef struct**, let's call them TS1 and TS2.

Now, the type of one member of TS1 is TS2.
I'd like that only TS1 is visible. TS2 should be hidden.
TS2 should be only visible to the ".c" file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the member declared as pointer or struct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to name private header files with the '-internal' suffix. For your example, I'd have

```
foobar.c
    #include "foobar-internal.h"
    #include "foobar.h"
    /* functions using `struct TS1` and `struct TS2` */
```

.

```
foobar.h
    #ifndef H_FOOBAR_INCLUDED
    #define H_FOOBAR_INCLUDED
    struct TS1;
    #endif
```

.

```
foobar-internal.h
    #ifndef H_FOOBAR_INTERNAL_INCLUDED
    #define H_FOOBAR_INTERNAL_INCLUDED
    struct TS2 { int whatever; };
    struct TS1 { int whatever; struct TS2 internal; };
    #endif
```

Any code using your functions, includes the simpler `"foobar.h"` and can use pointers to `struct TS1`. It cannot directly use objects of either `struct TS1` or `struct TS2` type. In fact, by including just `"foobar.h"`, the code has no idea there exists a `struct TS2` type anywhere and can redefine it to its own purposes.

```
usercode.c
    #include "foobar.h"
    struct TS1 *x;
    x = newTS1();
    work(x);
    destroyTS1(x);
```

Comment: Note that `private`is not a keyword in C.

Comment: @fnokke: thanks. I changed the identifier to internal to avoid confusions.

Comment: But when `foobar-internal.h` is never included anywhere, how can the compiler know the definition of `TS1` and `TS2`?

Comment: @NiklasR: it can't. You have to `#include "foobar-internal.h"` in some source file; tipically the source file that deals with the structs in question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Rumple.

What you can do instead is e.g. `#define TS2 int` in the .h and `#undef TS2` at the top of the .c file after the `#include`.

Though this doesn't use `typedef`. You can also `#undef` it in the bottom of the .h file if you want to `#include` it in multiple .c files.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible. But you can have 2 different .h files for TS1 and TS2.